# SqlDataSource FilterParameters and FilterExpression do not work with empty strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource, string

I have an `SqlDatasource` for which I programmatically create the `SelectCommand`.  In general, the `SqlDataSource` works fine, but when I give it `FilterParameters` and a `FilterExpression`, things go awry.  Below are two examples, the first returning 0 records, the second returning all the records (15,000).  Neither example returns the subset of records that I'm looking for (2,839).  I'm completely befuddled as to how I'm supposed to set up the `FilterParameters` and `FilterExpression` to get the records I'm looking for.  I've been researching this for two days now with no luck.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsIAMS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ReportsConnectionString %>" />

dl = (DropDownList)tFilters.Controls[0];
// dl.ID = dlPASUBTYPENAME 
cp = new ControlParameter();
cp.Name = "cp" + dl.ID.Substring(2);
cp.ControlID = dl.ID;
cp.PropertyName = "SelectedValue";

//Attempt 1:  Returns 0 records
cp.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
dsIAMS.FilterParameters.Add(cp);
if (dl.SelectedItem.Text == "") {
  dsIAMS.FilterExpression = dl.ID.Substring(2) + "='' ";
}
else {
  dsIAMS.FilterExpression = dl.ID.Substring(2) + "='{0}'";
}

//Attempt #2:  Returns all the records (15,000)
cp.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
dsIAMS.FilterParameters.Add(cp);
if (dl.SelectedItem.Text == "") {
  dsIAMS.FilterExpression = "ISNULL("+dl.ID.Substring(2) + ", 'null')='null' ";
}
else {
  dsIAMS.FilterExpression = dl.ID.Substring(2) + "='{0}'";
}
```

Here is the SQL query that I run against the database itself:

```
SELECT * FROM IAMS
WHERE PASUBTYPENAME IS NULL
```

Returns 2,839 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up.  In addition to`FilterExpression` and FilterParameters, I tried `SelectParameters` with the same results.  I decided to just hard code the whole `SelectCommand` every time.  Parameters just don't work.  I've always hated them because they simply to not handle NULLs well.  During my diagnosis, I even ran SQL Server Profiler to trace communication from Visual Studio and when the parameter wasn't used (i.e. the "ISNULL" part was used), the query was never even submitted to the SQL server.  I ended up using the following code instead:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsIAMS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ReportsConnectionString %>" />

dl = (DropDownList)tFilters.Controls[0];
// dl.ID = dlPASUBTYPENAME 
if (dl.SelectedItem.Text == "") {
  dsIAMS.SelectCommand+=dl.ID.Substring(2) + " IS NULL";
}
else {
  dsIAMS.SelectCommand+=dl.ID.Substring(2) + "='" + dl.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be doing a databind() following any FilterExpression setting for these Datasets or DropDownLists. You need to do this to invoke a requery.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Null values for `FilterParameters` you can
declare your full `FilterExpression` command in `SqlDataSource` eg,

`FilterExpression="Name = '{0}' AND Status = '{1}' AND Date = '{2}'"`.

Set `DefaultValue=` to any value for each of the `FilterParameters`. This will trigger the `OnFiltering` event since all parameters have a value.
In the `OnFiltering` event method set `sqlDS.FilterExpression = "";`.

Afterwards if you want to change the Filter Expression based of a Dropdown Select or Text Change, just assign `sqlDS.FilterExpression = "Date = '{2}'"`
inside the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` or `OnTextChanged` events for each `Control`.

Only downside is that this only allows you to filter by 1 Parameter unless you have nested if statements where you handle multiple parameters for the filter.